# I am getting two plots for one data set in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am working through example 8.1 titled *Euler's Method* from Mark Newman's book Computational Physics. I rewrote the example as a method with Numpy arrays but when I plot it I get two plots on the same figure not sure how to correct it. Also is there better way to convert my 2 1D arrays into 1 2D array to use for plotting in Matplotlib, thanks.

Newman's example :

```
from math import sin
from numpy import arange
from pylab import plot,xlabel,ylabel,show

def f(x,t):
    return -x**3 + sin(t)

a = 0.0           # Start of the interval
b = 10.0          # End of the interval
N = 1000          # Number of steps
h = (b-a)/N       # Size of a single step
x = 0.0           # Initial condition

tpoints = arange(a,b,h)
xpoints = []
for t in tpoints:
    xpoints.append(x)
    x += h*f(x,t)

plot(tpoints,xpoints)
xlabel("t")
ylabel("x(t)")
show()
```

My modifications:

```
from pylab import plot,show,xlabel,ylabel
from numpy import linspace,exp,sin,zeros,vstack,column_stack


def f(x,t):
    return (-x**(3) + sin(t))

def Euler(f,x0,a,b):
    N=1000    
    h = (b-a)/N
    t = linspace(a,b,N)
    x = zeros(N,float)
    y = x0
    for i in range(N):
        x[i] = y
        y += h*f(x[i],t[i])

    return column_stack((t,x)) #vstack((t,x)).T


plot(Euler(f,0.0,0.0,10.0))
xlabel("t")
ylabel("x(t)")
show()
```

Comment: I guess your first problem is that you need to clear the plot space somehow. I dont know Pyplot well enough, but in Matplotlib there is a `plt.clf()`

Comment: @Henry Just tried while it helps, the main linear plot still shows up for some reason it seems to take one data set and plot two graphs from it.

Comment: Ah sorry bro. No experience with pyplot!

Comment: @Henry It's all good clearing did help with another issue I was having the plots

Comment: @Henry `pyplot` **is** `plt` if you `import`ed `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Also `pylab` is is just a different namespace for `pyplot`.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get two lines is that `t` as well as `x` are plotted against their index, instead of `x` plotted against `t`

I don't see why you'd want to stack the two arrays. Just keep then separate, which will also solve the problem of the two plots.

The following works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = lambda x,t: -x**3 + np.sin(t)

def Euler(f,x0,a,b):
    N=1000    
    h = (b-a)/N
    t = np.linspace(a,b,N)
    x = np.zeros(N,float)
    y = x0
    for i in range(N):
        x[i] = y
        y += h*f(x[i],t[i])

    return t,x

t,x = Euler(f,0.0,0.0,10.0)
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("x(t)")
plt.show()
```